# Regex for NSLocalizedString for objectC with comments and without comments

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have two different below lines patterns in my file. I want regex pattern to create groups for string in double quotes in each line.

```
#define kvalue                        NSLocalizedString(@"value", comment:@"1223")
```

here group(1) = "value", group(2) = "1223"

```
#define kvalue                        NSLocalizedString(@"value", @"1223")
```

similarly here also group(1) = "value", group(2) = "1223"

i tried below regex but not getting expected result

```
stringwithComment = re.compile('NSLocalizedString\(@\s*"(.*?)"\s*,\s*comment:\s*\@"(.*?)"\s*\)',re.DOTALL )
```

Comment: What is the result you're getting?

Comment: #define kvalue                        NSLocalizedString(@"value"

Comment: @Rocker: Your regex is fine and capturing your intended text well. But I think you are capturing whole match instead of group1 and group2 which contains the data you need. Can you edit your post to include your python code you are using?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: will you help me to fix this?

Comment: @Rocker: Of course, please share your python code that you are using.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: #file is input parameter for function
 stringwithComment = re.compile('NSLocalizedString\(@\s*"(.*?)"\s*,\s*comment:\s*\@"(.*?)"\s*\)',re.DOTALL )
 f = open( file, 'r' )
    content = f.read()
    for result in stringwithComment.finditer(content):
            self.addObj(result.group(1),result.group(2))

Comment: @Rocker: Your code seems to be capturing the input correctly with `result.group(1),result.group(2)` I am little confused as to what issue you are actually facing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, your regex is fine but seems like you are not capturing group1 and group2 which contains the data you want to capture. Here is the sample code which will get you what you need.

```
import re

s = '#define kvalue                        NSLocalizedString(@"value", comment:@"1223")'
stringwithComment = re.compile('NSLocalizedString\(@\s*"(.*?)"\s*,\s*comment:\s*\@"(.*?)"\s*\)',re.DOTALL )
m = re.search(stringwithComment,s)
if m:
 print(m.group(1))
 print(m.group(2))
```

This prints,

```
value
1223
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you face any issues further.

Answer (score 1):

I think your pattern overcomplicates it. If you're just looking to capture those two strings, you can do it with:

```
x = '#define kvalue                        NSLocalizedString(@"value", comment:@"1223")'
re.findall("@\"(\w+)\"", x)
```

**Output**

```
['value', '1223']
```

[Demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=%40%5C%22(%5Cw%2B)%5C%22&test_string=%23define%20kvalue%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20NSLocalizedString(%40%22value%22%2C%20comment%3A%40%221223%22)%0A%23define%20kvalue%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20NSLocalizedString(%40%22value%22%2C%20%40%221223%22)&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: I am searching pattern across folder. using for result in 
      for result in stringwithComment.finditer(fileContent): its not working . Regex = re.compile("@\"(\w+)\"",re.DOTALL ) and its not working